# How to display measurement lengths in Blender 2.9?

Tags: edit-mode, measurement, gizmo

I want to get this result in **Blender 2.9**:

[image]

However for all the tutorials i searched online, all i could find were how to achieve this in Blender 2.8 as shown:

[image]

I assumed it would be under the gizmo panel in 2.9, but i can't seem to find the checkbox for it. All i get is this:
[image]

Where is the option to show measurements in Blender 2.9?

Comment: Hello :). It's still there, but you need to be in edit mode.

Comment: Yes this worked THANK YOU. Wow I feel so stupid right now, these features are really good at playing hide-and-seek...